# Calling base class method in cocos2dx

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

The following code snippet is objective c. It is calling base class init method.

```
[super init]
```

can you assist me to call the same in objective c++(COCOS2DX)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**In cocos2d-iphone**,

`self=[super init]` is used to initialize self as a object of its parent type. So For example if parent of self is CCLayer then it will be initialize as type CCLayer.

**So in cocos2d-x,**

What you can do is, You have to call init method of it parent. For the same case, as i describe above,
You have to call init method of CCLayer

so the translation of `[super init]` will be `CCLayer::init()`